# global in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am new to Matlab and have difficulty understanding global variables. For example

```
global x y z
```

What does `global` mean? Could you give me an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without `global`, a declared variable has a limited scope, that is, it cannot be used outside the "part" of matlab where it is declared.  [This wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(programming)) has a decent discussion of what scope is in a generic sense.

For Example, if you declare a variable inside a function definition, then that variable can only be used inside that function - not in another function.  If you define a function at the command line (the so-called "base workspace") it cannot be used in functions.

`global` defines a variable in the ["global" scope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_variable) - it can be used anywhere, in any function, etc.  Except in limited cases, it is generally a bad idea, since it makes controlling how and when a variable has changed very difficult.  You are usually better off returning something from a function, then passing it to another.

Answer (score 4):

The keyword `GLOBAL` in MATLAB lets you define variables in one place and have them visible in another. The statement `global x y z` declares `x` `y` and `z` to be global. If that definition were placed inside a function scope, and a corresponding `global` definition in a separate function, then the two functions can share data without the need to pass parameters. Like so:

```
%% fcn1.m
function fcn1( val )
global store
store = val

%% fcn2.m
function y = fcn2()
global store
y = store;
```

Thus you can call `fcn1` to store a value, and use `fcn2` to retrieve the value later.

Using `GLOBAL` data in this way hides the dependencies between your functions, and is considered pretty bad practice.

Comment: could  we  say  that  global variables  among  functions likes the attributes in a class?

Comment: Not at all.  global defines a variable shared by every part of matlab.  Actually the exact opposite of class attributes.